Power indicator circuit with overcurrent signaling
I'm seeking advice on a circuit I've developed through experimentation, patience, and determination.
While I have a technical education in electronics and electric systems from middle school, I'm not an engineer. I'm curious if there's a way to safeguard the circuit from damage when connected to 400V or exposed to current surges in the CT's primary wiring.
The circuit is a power indicator with an overcurrent indicator based on a current transformer. It features a green LED indicating "POWER OK" when the current consumption is below I3, a value derived from the characteristics diagram of an automatic circuit breaker. As the current approaches this threshold, signaling a potential trip within an hour, the LED switches to red. It transitions quickly, typically from green to red around 17A to 18A. I can adjust the threshold with the potentiometer. The I3 value for a C16A circuit breaker is around 18.03A.
I tested it with an old-style dimmer with PAR cans used as a load, creating a scenario of an overcurrent situation and ensuring the circuit remains immune to noise and interference. After some research, I successfully adjusted the circuit to respond to overall current, ignoring noise/interference generated by the dimmer. Somehow, those two capacitors with the 1N4007 do the job. The burden resistor was not needed, as adding it didn't improve anything in my circuit - or maybe I am missing something here?
Occasionally, due to human error, the network source might have the neutral wire N swapped with one of the phases, resulting in 400V at power outlets, potentially damaging equipment. Though rare, I want to ensure my circuits can withstand this scenario. The circuit is intended to monitor standard power outlets (European Schuko) within the power distribution units I am constructing.

My priority is ensuring the circuit remains intact when connected to 400V. What can I do to improve in this regard?
How to prevent circuit failure in case of extended current surge in the CT?
And maybe there are better ways to ensure quicker switching when passing current threshold?

I'd appreciate input from professionals to identify any potential weaknesses. Any ideas?




